# xampp apache shutdown unexpectedly, same port and different ports still error

Tags: php, apache, xampp

someone can please help me how to fix this?
i want downgrade PHP version from 8.0 to 7.4, but when i downgrade the PHP version,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTdg7.png)

```
21:11:14  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
21:11:14  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
21:11:14  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
21:11:14  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
21:11:14  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
21:11:14  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
21:11:14  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
21:11:14  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

i try change the port from 80 to 8080, on apache httpd.conf. and still error, and i use another port still error. idk what happen, but if i turn back to PHP version 8.0 port 8080 can use.
any sollution about this please?
sorry for bad English

Comment: "Press the Logs button to view error logs" did you do that? If not, first delete all logs, then retry, finally copy new error-logs, and update your post with that.

Comment: i tried to open the logs but there's nothing word in the apache.error.logs

Answer (score 1):

Solved : i checked error on apache_start.bat , and my error just cant find properly file direction